# Firefox doesn't open when run on Jenkins server

Tags: windows, firefox, jenkins

I have the same problem，I'm using Firefox 57 and selenium 3.8.0,Jenkins on the linux ，windows 2008 R2。

It gives the following error log：

```
geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.18.0 

geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:54750 

geckodriver::marionette INFO Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette", "-headless"] *** You are running in headless mode. Marionette INFO Enabled via --marionette

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150063,name=PBrowser::Msg_ParentActivated) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24003F,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150080,name=PBrowser::Msg_LoadRemoteScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24003F,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24003F,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2400FA,name=PContent::Msg_AsyncMessage) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150001,name=PBrowser::Msg_AsyncMessage) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

l error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

Channel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

type=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv

!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

Comment: What are you doing? What's the problem? Do you try to run jasmine tests on jenkins?

Comment: I want to run the automated test case on Jenkins to use Firefox browsers，Here the error occurred，Please check the log for specific errors。

Answer (score 3):

Found this solution when browsing through internet, hope this helps

- Navigate to **C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref**
- Create a file *local-settings.js*
- Add below code to the .js file

`pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");
 pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);`

- Now create **mozilla.cfg** in  **C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
- Add below code to .cfg file

`//
pref("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);`

(Don't forget the // at the beginning of the file )

Rerun the jenkins build

Source:  https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/4208/jenkins-new-katalon-studio-5-1-0-2-firefox-wont-work